# Python - turtle program window opens but nothing happens

Tags: python

**I made this code and have no idea why it doesn't work. It's made in VS code**

Do you know how to make it works? I just started learning python and have no experience in it.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
turtle.speed(1)
window = turtle.Screen()
window.exitonclick()
def cd (turtle) :
    for i in range (6) :
        turtle.circle(80)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(100)

def reszta (turtle) :
    for i in range(8):
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.circle(50)
        
print (cd)
print (reszta)
turtle.done
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?  If not what is the problem?  What does it do or not do?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"Doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: I edited the title to describe the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

Programming advice: when you have a program that is not working but you don't have an error message or something to tell you what is wrong, try removing each part of your code until you get back to a simple program that works.  Then add each part back in one-by-one making sure to check that each part works before adding the next part.

That's how I came up with this answer:

```
import turtle
turtle.speed(1)

def cd(turtle):
    for i in range(6):
        turtle.circle(80)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(100)

def reszta(turtle):
    for i in range(8):
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(120)
        turtle.circle(50)
        
cd(turtle)
reszta(turtle)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created the functions `cd` and `reszta` so you need to call them not print them

You can do this just by typing

`cd()` and `reszta()`

***This is what you would do***

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
turtle.speed(1)
window = turtle.Screen()

def cd (turtle) :
    for i in range (6) :
        turtle.circle(80)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(100)

    def reszta (turtle) :
        for i in range(8):
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.right(120)
            turtle.circle(50)
cd(t)
reszta(t)
window.exitonclick()
turtle.done()
```